# Which visibility to choose for JNI controlled fields?

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I have a Java class which contains a native handle pointer which is only used by the native JNI methods. Let's use this class (Found at http://thebreakfastpost.com/2012/01/23/wrapping-a-c-library-with-jni-part-1/) as an example:

```
public class Plugin
{
    private long nativeHandle;

    protected Plugin(long handle) {
        nativeHandle = handle;
    }

    public native String getIdentifier();
    public native String getName();
    public native String getDescription();
    public native int getPluginVersion();
```

}

So the handle in this example is private. JNI doesn't care about the visibility. But source code analyzers like the one in Eclipse complain about the field because it is unused. Eclipse can't know that there is some JNI code which accesses this field.

Setting the field to protected or public is also a bad idea because then the handle can be modified from the outside (directly or by extending the class) which results in a crash. Package-private is not that bad but the default settings of source code analyzers like checkstyle complain about bad programming style.

Sure, I could add a `@SuppressWarnings("unused")` annotation to silence the eclipse warning or I could add some comment so checkstyle ignores the issue or disable the check in checkstyle completely. But I'm not sure if this is needed or if I simply do it wrong.

So is there some best practice for the visibility of native handles in classes which use JNI code? Or maybe they can be somehow avoided in Java code completely?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at java.lang.Thread src

```
/**
 * Dispatch an uncaught exception to the handler. This method is 
 * intended to be called only by the JVM.
 */
private void dispatchUncaughtException(Throwable e) {
    getUncaughtExceptionHandler().uncaughtException(this, e);
}
```

Eclipse would complain about the unused method, still it's private, comments help to understand why.

`@SuppressWarnings("unused")` is a good idea IMO

Answer (score 0):

Apart from disabling warning, I usually try to add a unit test which check the value of the field. e.g. you could check it is non-zero and different for different plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Hm... Maybe I found an alternative. Well, two alternatives actually. Both simply uses the private value for a real purpose so the code analyzer has no reason to complain about unused code.

The first alternative is using the native handle in `hashCode` and `equals`. This works fine for objects where this native handle is some kind of primary key (Device handles for example). It doesn't work for objects where it does make more sense to use some other data to identify the object (A user object may already have a user id for example).

```
public final Device
{
    /** The device handle. Set by native code. */
    private long handle;

    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + (int) (this.handle ^ (this.handle >>> 32));
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj)
    {
        if (this == obj) return true;
        if (obj == null) return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) return false;
        Device other = (Device) obj;
        if (this.pointer != other.pointer) return false;
        return true;
    }    
}
```

The second alternative is simply providing a getter for the native handle. Returning it is harmless because it still can't be modified from the outside. And it even may be useful if someone wants to write custom JNI code which use the native pointer to directly access the object with the native C API instead of using the Java API:

```
public final Device
{
    /** The device handle. Set by native code. */
    private long handle;

    public long getHandle()
    {
        return this.handle;
    }
}
```